# FaceBook LikeView like count don't refresh automatically in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have added `LikeView` to my `Android` application as following:

```
    LikeView likeView = (LikeView) lytMain.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
    likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
    likeView.setOnErrorListener(new LikeView.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i("test", "Facebook error " + error.toString());
        }
    });
            likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/mypage/",
                    LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Added application to `facebook` and when I press `LikeButton` every thing works and shows the current `like count`.

But when count increases in page like count does not refreshes automatically in my app.

To get new count i have to press `LikeButton` again, after that it shows refreshed count from my page.

### My question is:

*How can set auto refresh to my `LikeView` so that it shows fresh like count from my `Facebook page` every time when I open application?*